# How to insert a ternary operator in mysql statement

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a query, and in the where statement I want to insert a ternary operator like this:

```
WHERE 

 $self->is_defined? 'some_column = $self->defined' : 'some_other_column = $self->defined_some'
 AND blah blah blah
 AND blah blah blah
```

Something like that. How to do it?

As of now my code is this which doesnt work:

```
"SELECT blah blah blah

    WHERE 
     "$self->is_defined ? 'o.project_id = "$self->project_id"' : 'o.brand_id = "$self->brand_id"'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, method calls doesn't interpolate inside double quotes, and even less so inside single quotes.

You should use placeholders when creating sql in order to avoid [**sql injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection),

```
my $sql = "SELECT * from ... WHERE ";

my ($cond, $val) = $self->is_defined 
  ? ("some_column = ?", $self->defined)
  : ("some_other_column = ?", $self->defined_some);

# constructing final sql..
$sql .= $cond;

my $st = $db_handle->prepare($sql) or die $db_handle->errstr;
$st->execute($val) or die $st->errstr;
```

Comment: My code contains comma too, I removed it because I dont know what it does, Can you explain to me what the comma is used for there and the question mark too after the equal sign? Thanks

Comment: Ahhh. I know what the question mark does, it serves as a container to be replaced on the right part of the comma. Thanks

Comment: HEy, where is the sql statement there? i need it to insert to an sql statement

Comment: @user2881063: "servers as a container to be replaced on the right part of the comma" not quite; the commas are just there because you are assigning two values to two variables - a list assignment. the questionmark in the sql passed to *prepare* is a container to be replaced by what is passed to *execute* later on.